# Spring Security: allow user only to access their own administration page

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

In my web app users are able to change their user details. The URL for this page is:

```
springproject/usermanagement/edituserinfo/4
```

where "4" is the user id.

My security-context looks like:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/usermanagement" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/usermanagement/new" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/usermanagement/edit/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/usermanagement/edituserinfo/*" access="isAuthenticated()" />  
</security:http>
```

How can I restrict the user only to access their own "edituserinfo" page? E.g. user with user id 1 can only access: "springproject/usermanagement/edituserinfo/1 " and not "springproject/usermanagement/edituserinfo/4 "

Comment: Do you really need to pass the user id in the URL?  Ideally your URL should just be `springproject/usermanagement/edituserinfo`.  You should retrieve the user id in the Java code as `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` and use that to load the user details.  This will make sure that a user is only able to see and edit their own details and no one else's.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a `PathVariable` on the URL, like `@RequestMapping("/usermanagement/edituserinfo/{userid}")` and in your code validate the logged-in user's Spring Security context principle (via `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()`) against the `userid` path variable.  If they don't match,  bounce the user out, log a `SecurityException`, and send an email to the admins.

Answer (score 14):

You can also accomplish this using Spring Security's @PreAuthorize which supports expressions:

```
@PreAuthorize("#userId == principal.id")
public void doSomething(@PathVariable String userId);
```

See the Spring docs:

[Access Control using @PreAuthorize and @PostAuthorize](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#access-control-using-preauthorize-and-postauthorize)