# How to get the id of current logged in user from principal object in SpEL?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-el

I've seen a lot of code samples that look like this :

```
@RequestMapping("/user/{id}"}
@PreAuthorize("principal.userId == #id"}
public String getUrl(@PathVariable("id") Long id){

}
```

I don't understand how it is possible to have access to "userId" from the principal object directly. The only attribute I have access to when I try this is the name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Security: allow user only to access their own administration page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871203/spring-security-allow-user-only-to-access-their-own-administration-page)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing this in controller is using `Authentication` object. Try the below code

```
@RequestMapping("/user"}
public String getUrl(Authentication authentication){
    //Get current logged in user. 
    //If the user not logged in then authentication will be null
    String userName = authentication.getName();
}
```